# How to insert a duplicate element into a vector?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector

I'm trying to insert a copy of an existing `vector` element to double it up. The following code worked in previous versions but fails in Visual Studio 2010.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   vector<int> test;
   test.push_back(1);
   test.push_back(2);
   test.insert(test.begin(), test[0]);
   cout << test[0] << " " << test[1] << " " << test[2] << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output is `-17891602 1 2`, expected `1 1 2`.

I've figured out why it's happening - the vector is being reallocated, and the reference becomes invalid before it's copied to the insertion point. The older Visual Studio apparently did things in a different order, thus proving that one possible outcome of undefined behavior is to work correctly and also proving that it's never something you should rely on.

I've come up with two different ways to fix this problem. One is to use `reserve` to make sure that no reallocation takes place:

```
   test.reserve(test.size() + 1);
   test.insert(test.begin(), test[0]);
```

The other is to make a copy from the reference so that there's no dependency on the reference remaining valid:

```
template<typename T>
T make_copy(const T & original)
{
    return original;
}

   test.insert(test.begin(), make_copy(test[0]));
```

Although both work, neither one feels like a natural solution. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: BTW vc11 dev preview gives `1 1 2` for the first example.

Comment: @Jesse, that doesn't surprise me. The Rvalue overload of `insert` was being selected which seems like a bug that they might have fixed. The code is completely different between that overload and the one that takes a const reference.

Comment: @MarkRansom: This [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735732/stl-vector-of-vector-insertion-problem) seems to be it.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum, no it doesn't. Casting to `const int &` works, but I think that's just because it causes it to use the older code path. That's not a proper fix.

Comment: After 10 minutes of searching, I still cannot find the thread, but... at some point there was extensive discussion here on Stack Overflow about this, and the consensus was that an implementation had to ensure that the reference to `test[0]` was valid at least long enough to insert the element.  I.e., Visual C++ 2010's behavior is incorrect.  The Visual C++ 11 Beta has the correct behavior.

Comment: @Jesse, that does appear to be the same bug. I still believe that this condition is undefined behavior, unless someone can point to a spot in the standard saying this corner case is well defined.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, if you find that thread post a link to it and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I don't think there is much to choose between what you have suggested, you could take the value prior to the insertion like `int copy = test[0]; test.insert(test.begin(), copy);`

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `vector::insert` takes a reference to a value as the second parameter and not a value.  You don't need the template to make a copy, just use a copy constructor to create another object, which will be pass by reference.  This copy remains valid even if the vector is resized.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   vector<int> test;
   test.push_back(1);
   test.push_back(2);
   test.insert(test.begin(), int(test[0]));
   cout << test[0] << " " << test[1] << " " << test[2] << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just a test case. My actual code contains elements that are much more complicated than an int, and the constructor for a temporary just gets ugly. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is defined behavior. In `§23.2.3` of the 2011 C++ standard, table 100 lists sequence container requirements and there is an entry for this case. It gives the example expression

```
a.insert(p,t)
```

where `a` is a value of `X` which is a sequence container type containing elements of type `T`, `p` is a const iterator to `a`, and `t` is an lvalue or const rvalue of type `X::value_type`, i.e. `T`.

The assertion for this expression is:

> *Requires:* `T` shall be `CopyInsertable` into `X`. For `vector` and `deque`, `T` shall also be `CopyAssignable`. 
>   
> *Effects:* Inserts a copy of `t` before `p`.

The only relevant vector specific quote I could find is in `§23.3.6.5` paragraph 1:

> *Remarks:* Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity. If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid.

Although this does mention the vector being reallocated, it doesn't make an exception to the previous requirements for `insert` on sequence containers.

As for working around this issue, I agree with @EdChum's suggestion of just making a copy of the element and inserting that copy.

Comment: I don't see anything in your description that calls out the case where `t` is a reference to a member of `a`.