# std::vector is cleared automatically before returning it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, vector, return-value

I have this function,

```
vector<QDC::AdapterUserInfo> QDC::QueryInterface::RetrieveAdapterList()
{
    vector<QDC::AdapterUserInfo> retVal;
    InnerQueryInterface::IISTATE::Transition trans = _IQI->AdapterList(retVal);
    if (trans._OldState == trans._NewState)
    {
        if ( trans._NewState != InnerQueryInterface::IISTATE(trans._OldState).SuccessfulTransition(trans._Transition) )
        {
            throw Exceptions::FunctionFailed();
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

`QDC` is a namespace. `QueryInterface` is a class which is exported using `__declspec(dllexport)`. ( DLL with lib is generated )
In some other project i use this function as follows,

```
vector<QDC::AdapterUserInfo> aui = Qui.RetrieveAdapterList();
```

But the vector always returns with size 0 in Release build. But returns with size 1 ( which is the actual number of elements ). I debugged it in the release mode and found that `retVal` inside the `RetrieveAdapterList` function is filled with the actual data and then at the last line of the function, which is `return retVal;` line, it shows that the `retVal` vector is `cleared` to become empty. so the value returned at the end is an empty vector.

Why is this happening? what is wrong? why is it working on Debug mode?

--EDIT--

It seems that the Destructor of the vector `aui` fails after continuing execution to the end of its scope.

-- Code from Caller --

```
void DXE::Screen::Initialize( const HWND in_Window, const bool in_Windowed )
{
    QDC::UsableParameters UP;
    QDC::QueryInterface Qui;
    vector<QDC::AdapterUserInfo> aui = Qui.RetrieveAdapterList();
    if( aui.size() <= 0 )
    {
        throw Exceptions::UnknownException();
    }
    Qui.SelectAdapter(0);
    Qui.SelectDisplayMode(in_Windowed);
    UP = Qui.RetrieveParameters();

    _AdapterOrdinal = UP._AdapterOrdinal;

    _D3DPresentParams.BackBufferWidth = UP._Width;
_D3DPresentParams.BackBufferHeight = UP._Height;
_D3DPresentParams.BackBufferFormat = UP._BackBufferFormat;
    //..... fills the _D3DPresentParams..
}
```

-- EDIT : Conclusion --

After many attempts an error message came saying that a heap crash may have occurred, which drives the reason suggested by Peter Ruderman. So then I changed from using a Dynamic Library to Static Library so that such heap stuff may not happen in that case ( at least that's what i was thinking ). Then the program seemed to work fine without any problem. So the conclusion should be that Peter's theory was correct. Thank you all for helping out.

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: at the time i am trying to replicate the bug in a simple data structure. ill post it if i would be able to replicate this bug.

Comment: The only place I can see that could fill retVal is in `_IQI->AdapterList(retVal)`.  Does this function take a reference or a pointer?

Comment: "I debugged it in the release" This is almost never a good idea. What you ahve shown works: Whatever value `retVal` has at the return statement is what `aui` will have. If `aui` is empty, it means that `retVal` was empty. Be sure you're certain `aui` is actually empty before you investigate how `retVal` was emptied (and no, the compiler is not automatically breaking your program). If `retVal` is empty, it means either `_IQI->AdapterList(retVal);` did nothing to it, or it's somehow getting cleared in the loop. Debug a debug build and check it out from there.

Comment: the problem is that in Debug build, it works perfectly. but in the Release build `aui` is empty, and `retVal` is emptied at the bottem of the function. I double checked this with optimizations off and debug info On for Release build.

Comment: Can you post the code from the call site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another theory:

"QDC is a namespace. QueryInterface is a class which is exported using __declspec(dllexport). ( DLL with lib is generated )"

If I understand this correctly, you're saying that the function Screen::Initialize resides in your executable module but the function QueryInterface::RetrieveAdapters list resides in a DLL.  In this case, your DLL is allocating the memory and then *moving* it to the call site.  When aui goes out of scope, your exe deletes the memory.  If the DLL and exe are using different heaps, this can cause serious errors (heap corruption).

Comment: yes they are from different residences. Wow i never thought of that. I'll see if that is the reason.

Comment: does a DLL has its own kinda heap? pardon me, i am not very experienced. the DLL was written in the simplest way i can. its just a bunch of small number of functions with lots of std::set and std::vector elements.

Comment: That depends.  If both the DLL and the application are dynamically linked to the _exact_ same version of the CRT, then they will share a heap.  If they are linked to different versions or are statically linked, then they will each have their own.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx

Comment: So how can i avoid this? by passing in as a reference? or any other way?

Comment: In principal that could be quite difficult. The design is a little fragile. In general, all memory allocated by a DLL should be freed by that same DLL. That includes any memory allocated for the vector and any memory allocated internally by the objects it holds. If you've verified that this is the problem (and you can't fix it by changing your compiler settings), then I recommend asking another question on what to do about it.

Comment: This article seems to do a good job of laying our your options for fixing the DLL interface: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the source of your bug.  In the early version of C++11 which VS2010 uses, vectors are move constructible.  In your return statement, the local variable retval becomes an rvalue, so the compiler moves its contents into the "aui" variable at the call site.  (Effectively, it justs swaps the contents of aui and retval.)  You should see this behaviour if you trace through the debug build as well.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like maybe the OP is looking at the debugger and checking the local `retVal` *after* the return, which aught to end up as garbage or zeroed memory after the move out of the function.

Comment: i guess maybe u r rite. but the problem is `aui` is not showing any elements. :(

Comment: @Deamonpog, which version of VS are you using, is it VS2010? I've seen one bug with vector move semantics in it, perhaps this is a manifestation or perhaps it's a different bug.

Comment: yes its VS2010. wht is that bug? it seems VS2008 was better :P

Comment: @Deamonpog, if you read the comments to my question you'll find a link to a Microsoft bug report: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218223/how-to-insert-a-duplicate-element-into-a-vector